# jquery code when running second time doesn't get the same result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've the following jquery code

```
$(function(){
    function darkBox(div){
        var w = (div.attr('width')) ? div.attr('width') : div.width();
        var h = (div.attr('height')) ? div.attr('height') : div.height();

        var box = $('<div></div>').addClass('darkCover');
        $('body').prepend(box);
        box.fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
        $(this).keydown(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 27){
                box.hide();
                contentBox.hide();
            }
        });

        var contentBox = $('<div></div>').html(div.html());
        contentBox.addClass('darkContent');

        var x = $(window).width()/2;
        var y = $(window).height()/2;
        var startW = h-y/2;
        var startH = w-x/2;
        var endTop = y - h/2;
        var endLeft = x - w/2;

        contentBox.css("left", x+"px");
        contentBox.css("top", startW+"px");
        contentBox.css("z-index", "910");
        contentBox.css("width", w+"px");
        contentBox.css("height", h+"px");

        $('body').prepend(contentBox);

        contentBox.animate({
            opacity: 1,
            width:w+"px",
            height:h+"px",
            top:endTop+"px",
            left:endLeft+"px"
        }, 1000, "easeOutExpo");


    }

    $('.darkBox').each(function(){
        var div = $($(this).attr('data-target'));
        div.hide();
        $(this).click(function(){
            darkBox(div);
        });
    });

});
```

**EDIT**
HTML :

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-target="#useThisDiv1" class="btn blue btn-xs darkBox">Show Box1</a>
<div id="useThisDiv1" width="500" height="500">
    <h3 class="breadcrumb">Div1</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

.darkContent{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #333;
    font-family: arial;
}
.darkCover{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 900;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**END EDIT**

on the above code if i click it first time i get a black background with opacity of 80% but if i click it again i get white background. I'll show you those two screen shots

Image with opaque background
[image: Image with opaque background]

Image with white background
[image: Image with white background]

and to be preciously on the code, the following code only executes once i guess

```
var box = $('<div></div>').addClass('darkCover');
$('body').prepend(box);
box.fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
```

Can I run the above code every time I click the button to open popup window... any suggestions?

Regards

Comment: Do you remove <div class="darkCover"></div> after hiding it? or you just prepend new one?

Comment: NO nothing is happening outside this code there is a anchor tag and couple of div's tags with a unique ids

Comment: Can you post some sample HTML code to use with the darkBox function?

Comment: okay let me edit my post

Comment: try adding $('.darkCover').remove();$('.darkContent').remove(); in the beginning of the darkBox function. In this way you will delete the old unnecessary html. Maybe they cause the problem, but without real html im not sure.

Comment: no @AlexG no it didn't work :(

Comment: @NicolasMalbran and AlexG post updated

Comment: Its working fine for me :) i can send you the test page i have created based on the html/script you send me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the full html page. Its working ok, i only needed to remove easing because i didn't included it. This is same as yours code only added remove part to keep clean html, tested in chrome.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Test Page</title> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>

.darkContent{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #333;
    font-family: arial;
}
.darkCover{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 900;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>

</head> 
<body> 
    <a href="javascript:;" data-target="#useThisDiv1" class="btn blue btn-xs darkBox">Show Box1</a>
<div id="useThisDiv1" width="500" height="500">
    <h3 class="breadcrumb">Div1</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    <script>
     $(function(){
    function darkBox(div){
        $('.darkCover').remove();
        $('.darkContent').remove();
        var w = (div.attr('width')) ? div.attr('width') : div.width();
        var h = (div.attr('height')) ? div.attr('height') : div.height();

        var box = $('<div></div>').addClass('darkCover');
        $('body').prepend(box);
        box.fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
        $(this).keydown(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 27){
                box.hide();
                contentBox.hide();
            }
        });

        var contentBox = $('<div></div>').html(div.html());
        contentBox.addClass('darkContent');

        var x = $(window).width()/2;
        var y = $(window).height()/2;
        var startW = h-y/2;
        var startH = w-x/2;
        var endTop = y - h/2;
        var endLeft = x - w/2;

        contentBox.css("left", x+"px");
        contentBox.css("top", startW+"px");
        contentBox.css("z-index", "910");
        contentBox.css("width", w+"px");
        contentBox.css("height", h+"px");

        $('body').prepend(contentBox);

        contentBox.animate({
            opacity: 1,
            width:w+"px",
            height:h+"px",
            top:endTop+"px",
            left:endLeft+"px"
        }, 1000);


    }

    $('.darkBox').each(function(){
        var div = $($(this).attr('data-target'));
        div.hide();
        $(this).click(function(){
            darkBox(div);
        });
    });

});
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: thanks @AlexG that works I actually was working wit jquery 1.1, changed it to current version it worked... regards